# PSQL Find Common Values In Different Groups

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have a bunch of `team_id`'s.

```
team_id|username
-------|--------
      1|      u1
      1|      u2
      2|      u3
      2|      u1
      2|      u2
      3|      u1
      3|      u2
      3|      u4
```

So for every `team_id` I want to find if any two users are always have the same `team_id.` So in the example above, the query should return `u1` and `u2` since they always in the same team. Kind of hard to explain...any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

build data:

```
t=# create table so17(team_id int,username text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# copy so17 from stdin delimiter '|';
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>>       1|      u1
      1|      u2
      2|      u3
      2|      u1
      2|      u2
      3|      u1
      3|      u2
      3|      u4>> >> >> >> >> >> >>
>> \.
COPY 8
```

select:

```
t=# with e as (with i as (select *,array_agg(team_id) over (partition by username) from so17)
select distinct username,count(1) over (partition by array_agg) from i)
select username from e where count > 1;
 username
----------
       u2
       u1
(2 rows)
```